# Split stdin by lines

Tags: bash, io-redirection, pipe

I want to invoke a command for every line of the standard input, much like `xargs`, but the line should be passed as standard input, not as a command-line argument:

```
cat some-file.txt | <magic> | wc -c
```

- this should print the number of characters in each line of the file.

What are my options?

Comment: It's unfortunate that the actual issue only is hinted at at the end of the question. It would be more interesting to work with the code that you were actually trying to run, together with an example of the input file. The given code does not say much about where the problem lies. It might be a buffering issue, which would be easily fixed.

Comment: @Kusalananda I disagree, I think linewise execution as a general technique is much more interesting (and something I was able to use for a number of other problems once I learned about it) than some specific application of jq (which has an `--unbuffered` flag these days but didn't back then).

Comment: In that case, I'll remove the mentioning of `jq` at the end of the question, as it implies that the data is in fact not line-based at all but structured.  Any answer using line-based tools would therefore be inadequate in various ways.  Also note that although the question is almost ten years old, answers may be added that solves it using up-to-date tools.

Comment: Would not `awk '{ print length }'` as the second and final stage of the pipeline solve the particular problem here? Or were you stuck having to call `wc -c` specifically?  The question is whether the issue is philosophical (and the commands shown are examples) or actual (and you actually want to count the length of each line in a particular way).

Comment: FWIW, single-line JSON is a common log format. I'm pretty sure `wc` was just a random example.

Answer (score 7):

How about a plain loop

```
while IFS= read -r line ;
do
   printf "%s" "$line" | wc -c
done < some-file.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

A while-read loop is the most clear. If you want to use xargs to do something for each line, you may end up with a monstrosity like this:

```
printf "%s\n" "foo bar" one " 1 2 3" | 
xargs -d '\n' -n 1 -I LINE bash -c 'wc -c <<< "LINE"'
```

```
8
4
7
```

Pretty expensive since you have to spawn a bash process for each line.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat file.txt | while IFS= read -r i; do echo -n "$i" | wc -c; done
##  or (better):
while IFS= read -r i; do echo -n "$i" | wc -c; done < file.txt
```

However, this will *just* print the number of characters on a line, one line at a time. If you want something more readable, you might want one of the following:

```
##  Prints the contents of each line underneath the character count:
while IFS= read -r i; do echo -n "$i" | wc -c; echo "$i"; done < file.txt
##  Prints the line number alongside the character count:
n=0; while IFS= read -r i; do n=$((n+1)); echo -n "line number $n : "; echo -n "$i" | wc -c; done < file.txt
```

For greater portability you could use `printf '%s' "$i"` instead of all the `echo -n`s

Answer (score 1):

## Z shell

Storing lines into a variable can be avoided using option `-e`

```
setopt pipefail
cat some-file.txt |
  
  while read -re | wc -c
  do
  done
```

`-r` reads `\`s as they are

`-e` echoes the input instead of assigning it to any variable

`pipefail` makes `read -re | wc -c` exit with non-zero status code as soon as so does `read -re`, which it will at the end of the file

Unfortunately, this option isn't available in Bash